# Why does a parallel plate capacitor discharge itself?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

If in a RC circuit with no battery, there is a parallel plate capacitor having charge $Q$ and a resistor of resistance $R$. To satisfy *Kirchhoff's voltage law* (KVL) current must flow from the capacitor and it must discharge itself. But in the very first place why do positive charges start leaving from the positive plate? I want to know the mechanism instead of getting an answer as "KVL says so, that's why it discharges".

Comment: If KVL says so. Who is KVL? :-)

Comment: google-"Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL) is Kirchhoff's second law that deals with the conservation of energy around a closed circuit path. ... His voltage law states that for a closed loop series path the algebraic sum of all the voltages around any closed loop in a circuit is equal to zero."

Comment: Please make your question self-contained so no guesswork is required.

Comment: KVL is universally known

Comment: You are making a VBA.

Comment: A very broad assumption that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does positive charges start leaving from the positive plate

In the absence of any other sources of electric fields, there is an electric field not only between the plates of a capacitor, but also through any circuit connecting the plates of the capacitor.

When a circuit is made that allows a capacitor to discharge, the electric field in the wire causes electrons to flow from the wire into the positively charged plate (thus reducing it's net positive charge.

At the same time the electric field in the wire causes electrons in the wire to move toward the positive plate of the capacitor. These replace the electrons that move from the wire into the capacitor.

Also at the same time, the electric field causes electrons in the negatively charged plate to move into the wire, replacing electrons that are moving down the wire.

This process comes to a stop when there is no more charge in the capacitor, and therefore no more electric field induce in the wire by the capacitor.